# Hibernate join design

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have the following entities, each mapped to a table in the DB:

Campaign 
Business
Client

Campaign entity holds the business that the campaign was opened for.
Client entity holds the business it belongs to. I get the campaign's clients by searching for all the clients who have the same business_id as the campaign (guess this design could be improved).

I need to find all campaign clients that were entered into the system since the last time the campaign was run and send the campaign to them as well. What would be the best design for this?

I think I need to create a new entity called CampaignClient (client of a specific campaign) but I don't know how to implement this with Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

```
select client from campaign campaign
inner join campaign.business business
inner join business.clients client
where client.creationDate > campaign.lastRunDate
```

Or, if you don't have an association from business to clients (but you should have one):

```
select client from campaign campaign
inner join campaign.business business
where client.business.id = business.id 
and client.creationDate > campaign.lastRunDate
```

Comment: How will it work if I have multiple campaigns per-business (and hence multiple campaigns per-client as well)? The client might be new for some campaigns and "old" (already processed) for campaigns that ran recently.

Comment: My query didn't include the where `campain.id = :id` clause, which allows returning all the clients of a specific campaign. If you have several campaigns, use `select client, campaign from ...`. Each returned row will contain a client and a campaign to send to this client.